# how to make object fall with gravity

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can i change my objects gravity without having my player fall with it. I added

```
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```

on my players movement and affectedByGravity on both my object and player. If I change dy to -9.8, my object falls but along with my player. I tried setting my affectedByGravity to = false but then my player stops moving

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    guard isGameOver == false else { return }
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        if let currentTouch = lastTouchPosition {
            let diff = CGPoint(x: currentTouch.x - player.position.x, y: 0)
            physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: diff.x / 100, dy: diff.y / 100)
        }
    #else
        if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
            physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 5, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 0)
        }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the player stops moving when you set its `affectedByGravity` to `false`? Like you can't control it, or it doesn't fall when you jump, etc?

Comment: It just doesnt move. I made affectedByGravity = false so my player will not fall but keep moving while my enemy will fall

Comment: The description is still a bit confusing. If you set `affectedByGravity`, it shouldn't fall since gravity no longer has an effect on it.

Comment: Yea it doesnt fall if i set it to false but then it wont move. It moves if i remove affectedByGravity from my func or just change it to true.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. If you can link a repo where I can test it, that may help

Comment: Idk how to do that. Should i just show you my player movement code, because i think thats what might be causing this

Comment: Anything that can reproduce the issue, in code that can be run be anyone, would be good. A [mre]. It's hard to debug a problem like this without code. May as well add movement code to question though

Comment: i have physicsWorld.gravity in that code. So if i change gravity to -9.8 with that other line of code at the very top both of them will fall and thats the issue.

Comment: Does swift just not allow having two gravity values for two different objects. Also, has it worked for you yet?

Comment: I can't try running a project to test it. However, I think gravity is just universal for the whole 'world'. I'm not experienced enough in SpriteKit to know, sorry.

Comment: Hi Nathan. Why are you expecting your object to move, if not due to gravity? The code you added shows setting gravity from the accelerometer, but your player isn't affected by gravity so you wouldn't expect it to move. Is there something else going on (apart from gravity) that you think should be causing the player to move?

Comment: I want it to move on the x axis. When i add gravity for the enemy it will fall but so does my player. The only thing that should be falling is my enemy while i control my player left and right.